# How to profile filter out 2nd and 3rd level subdomains from GA?

Tags: regex, google-analytics

First off this is *primarily* to group webmail sources, as these are the largest offender of the many split up entries I get in GA

I want to start merging traffic sources that use two or three subdomains such as `us-mg205.mail.yahoo.com` or `us.mg5.mail.yahoo.com`

Would like all of these to be grouped under `mail.yahoo.com` in this case

*Edit: Based on @Crayon Violent's caveat I checked into my traffic records and I found that approximately 0.0007% of visits in the last month would be impacted by the country code effect (and not also be obviously webmail)*

I suppose one could also look for the word "mail" to match as a condition in the regex... I'll leave that for another question (or it can be "bonus")

In short, **really this is more of a GA profile filter setup question than a regex question**;

I'm happy with filtering using the number of dots in a domain only at this point using a pattern such as `([a-z0-9]*\.)*[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+\.[a-z0-9]+`

I'm just not sure how to set up the appropriate advanced profile filter in Google Analytics to make that work

Answer (score 1):

**Filter type:** `Custom Filter` **>** `Search and Replace`

**Filter Field:** `Referral`

**Search String:** `^https?://[^/?#]*\.?mail\.yahoo\.com([/?#].*)?`

**Replace String:** `https://mail.yahoo.com\1`

**Case Sensitive:** `No`

note that filters do not get applied to historical data.

Comment: Hi thank You. To help clarify mail.yahoo.com was just an example, I'm hoping to be able to do this for any source that has more than one subdomain. Maybe you could tweak this as such?

Comment: @Drewdavid You aren't going to be able to reliably do this for arbitrary domains. Not within the GA interface. And it's kind of a pita even doing it with code on your site, too. For example, you can't really account for `www.somesite.com` vs `www.somesite.co.uk` without a using (and maintaining) a massive lookup table of current TLDs to determine how many dots back count as the subdomains